# Handling null in java streams with optional

Tags: java, java-8, null, option-type

What would be the best way of handling null if we have senario like below

```
//mocking for demonstraton  
studentsByCourseRoster.setUsers(null);

studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers().stream().forEach(user -> {
    final UserDTOv2 userDTO = new UserDTOv2();
    userDTO.populateUserDataFromUserDTO(user, groupedUsers);
    users.add(userDTO);
});
```

Comment: where do you have to handle `null`?

Comment: How about `if(studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers() != null)`?

Comment: Just don’t set users to `null`. Allowing a `List` to become `null` (rather than empty), is a sign of a defective software design. Instead of adding workarounds at the reading side, fix the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to retain the single statement structure, you could use `Optional.ofNullable` and replace `null` with an empty list:

```
Optional.ofNullable(studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers())
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .forEach(user -> {
                     final UserDTOv2 userDTO = new UserDTOv2();
                     userDTO.populateUserDataFromUserDTO(user, groupedUsers);
                     users.add(userDTO);
         });
```

Comment: you do not need to `.stream()` btw, as a matter of fact, this violates the spec with that `.stream()`

Comment: @Eugene good point thanks. I tried to have the minimal set of changes from the OP's code, but you're right, the `stream()` call is redundant. I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

With a slight modification to Mureinik's answer I would instead use :

```
List<UserDTOv2> users = Optional.ofNullable(studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers())
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .stream()
        .map(user -> {
            UserDTOv2 userDTO = new UserDTOv2();
            userDTO.populateUserDataFromUserDTO(user, groupedUsers);
            return userDTO;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

#### Using [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) in Java 9

```
List<UserDTOv2> users = Stream.ofNullable(studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers())
        .map(user -> {
            UserDTOv2 userDTO = new UserDTOv2();
            userDTO.populateUserDataFromUserDTO(user, groupedUsers);
            return userDTO;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way of handling null if we have senario like
>   below

The simplest solution to that under your current design is to do so with an `if` statement.

That is not saying it's the best way to "handle" this problem but rather the *best way to handle* this is never to allow the list to be in a null state in the first place as also mentioned in the comments.

Have an empty list as the default value, this will save you quite a huge amount of `if` checks around your codebase depending on how many times `getUsers()` is being used and most importantly you wouldn't have to worry about `NullPointerExeception`'s because they should never occur.

On another note, whenever you seem to see your self calling `stream()` on some collection and then immediately calling `forEach` you should realise it's wrong; 1) in the sense that you could easily call `forEach` directly on the list i.e. `studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers().forEach(...)` 2) streams and side-effect just don't work together well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter null objects by filter(Objects::nonNull):

```
studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(user -> {
    final UserDTOv2 userDTO = new UserDTOv2();
    userDTO.populateUserDataFromUserDTO(user, groupedUsers);
    users.add(userDTO);
});
```

Comment: Actually, the list is null first-hand, so you will get NPE right at `studentsByCourseRoster.getUsers()`

Comment: If there were empty collection, i will not get NPE. Streams process all elements of a source, if there are no elements, no action will be taken.

Comment: Maybe you should try to run your code with `studentsByCourseRoster.setUsers(null);`, even the IDE can detect Null variable access

Answer (score 0):

One more way to write this with optional, in addition to correct @Murenik's answer. No need to create empty list, we can pass execution non null case only with:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(nullableUsers)
            .ifPresent(users -> users.forEach(user -> {
                // work with user
            }));
```

Nullable optional is also works very well with nested null references, e.g. we have some structure:

```
class User {
    @Getter
    Address address;
}

class Address {
    @Getter
    String street;
}
```

then instead of writing

```
if (user.getAddress() != null && user.getAddress().getStreet() != null) {
   // work with street
}
```

we can use Optional:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(user)
            .map(User::getAddress)
            .map(Address::getStreet)
            .ifPresent(street -> {
                // work with street
            });
```